# Increasing frequency resolution in numpy DFTs

Tags: python, numpy, signal-processing, fft, interpolation

I am working on an algorithm using NumPy's FFT system that requires me to get additional high-frequency information past the sampling frequency from a (perfectly known) signal (see: a rectangular pulse). For example: I have a signal that has 100 data points, but that is perfectly known. If I want to get the Fourier component of 2/t0 the spacing using NumPy, I need to have more available data points in the signal, and thus the FFT. How could I go about accomplishing this?

My current stratagem is to redefine the signal over 2N data points, and take the FFT of that. This does indeed produce additional high-frequency information, but it also distorts the low-frequency information, and I can't figure out why. For the simple 1D tests that I've run, the real values are multiplied by what appears to be a cosine wave, while the imaginary are multiplied by a similar sine wave compared to the original low-frequency information. Am I doing the upsampling wrong somehow? Where in the FFT is this pattern coming from, and what can I do to get higher-frequency information from this signal?

The code that generates this test is below. Thank you for any help you can give!

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.fft as fft
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
x1=np.linspace(0,30,31) #generate x points for comparison

#generate first mask
test1=np.zeros(31)
test1[10:21]=1

#plot first mask
plt.scatter(x1,test1)
plt.title("Original Signal")
plt.show()

map1=fft.fftshift(fft.fft(test1)) #FFT
plt.scatter(x1,np.log(np.abs(map1)+1)) #plot FFT
plt.title("Original Signal FT")
plt.show()
x2=np.linspace(0,61,62) #generate double x points

#generate and plot second mask. Matches up well
test2=np.zeros(62)
test2[20:42]=1
plt.scatter(x2,test2)
plt.title("Upsampled Signal")
plt.show()

#FFT and plot second mask (real parts default). works well
map2=(fft.fft(test2))
plt.scatter(x2,np.log(np.abs(map2)+1))
plt.title("Upsampled Signal FT")
plt.show()

#grab the central part of the second mask fft, compare to the original
mapset=np.concatenate((map2[-15:],map2[0:16]))
plt.scatter(x1,np.log(np.abs(mapset)+1))
plt.title("Low-Frequency (Matching) Components of Upsampled FT")
plt.show()

#show ratio of real and complex parts
plt.scatter(x1,np.real(mapset/map1),c='r')
plt.scatter(x1,np.imag(mapset/map1),c='b')
plt.legend(['Real Ratio','Imaginary Ratio'])
plt.show()
```

P.S. It should be noted that I expect a ratio of 2 between the upsampled and the original to account for the different numbers of samples in the signal.

Comment: What do you mean by "a (perfectly known) signal"?
What do you mean by "redefine the signal over 2N data points"?